# Mongodb server sockets closed on replSet

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets

We're having a problem with mongodb sockets closing on us when we do a high volume of connections in parallel.

Here's a test script:

```
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
var async = require("async");

mongodb.MongoClient.connect("mongodb://mongo-dev1:27017/test", function(err, db) {
    if (err) { throw err; }

    var calls = [];

    var col = db.collection("test");

    var count = 10000;
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        (function(i) {
            calls.push(function(cb) {
                console.time("update_" + i);
                col.update({ i : i }, { i : i }, { upsert : true }, function(err) {
                    console.timeEnd("update_" + i);

                    cb(err);
                });
            });
        })(i);
    }

    async.parallel(calls, function(err) {
        if (err) { throw err; }

        console.log("done");
    });
});
```

If I run that script, it will fail with the following error `MongoError: server mongo-dev1:27017 sockets closed`

The output of the log from mongodb itself is

`SocketException handling request, closing client connection: 9001 socket exception [SEND_ERROR] server [192.168.1.111:53556]`

What I can't figure out is what mechanism is causing the socket to close. I believe that the Node side of the equation is hanging up since my timing of events shows the Node close event occurring milliseconds before the SocketException in the mongodb logs. I've gone into the `mongodb` package into `mongodb-core` and did some `console.log` and the initiator for the event is `at TCP.close (net.js:485:12)`. This tells me that the socket itself is closing. Based on that it really feels like linux itself is closing the socket or the mongoDB host box and that it's not Node or MongoDB that's doing it. I'm not sure how to prove this though.

Here is the first set of options that I considered, but have ruled out:

1. Socket timeout - If it was a timeout, the error message is different, I verified this by passing the `socketTimeoutMS` option when I construct the connection. If I pass something small I'll get the timeout error.
2. MongoDB out of connections - If I monitor the connections on the mongodb replset using `db.serverStatus().connections` I still have plenty of available connections.
3. This behavior does not replicate when I communicate with a localhost non-replica set. That may be a localhost thing, or it may be a replica set thing.
4. If I change the parallel to a parallelLimit of 100, it finishes without a problem. Since Node uses a connection pool, whether I sent 1000 in parallel or 100 at a time in parallel it should amount to the same amount of traffic to MongoDB because they are all forced into the same 10 sockets. This helps to guide me that it's a Node problem.

Using Node 10, Node 12 and MongoDB 2.6

Comment: I occasionally bump into the same exception on production (using Mongo 3.0.3 replica set). I have not found a solution so far. One observation is that these exceptions are more likely to happen when the primary server is under heavy load...

Comment: That is a similar observation I've had. If I perform this test on our live servers the threshold before I start to get closed sockets is around 1000 in parallel, compared to ~7000 in our dev environment with no latent load.

Comment: I hope, somebody on MongoDB team will shed some light on this. I personally think that MongoDB needs to do a better job at collecting data on what triggered each replica set failover. I wish there was a simple command that dumps the status of all key resources at the moment when Mongo made the decision to fail over. Right now it's hard to tell whether there was a bottleneck around a particular hardware resource, or network glitch or some crazy query, etc.

Comment: I have a very similar situation with the same sockets closed problem and have been unable to find a good answer anywhere. Hopefully someone can shed some light.

Comment: What do you get when you put in the terminal db.serverStatus().connections ?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem under heavy load, however when digging into the mongodb driver I found out that the default values for the socketTimeout and connectTimeout are set to 30000 ms.

Raising them both solved my problem:

```
mongodb://m1.url.xyz:27017,m2.url.xyz:27017/test?replicaSet=myset&connectTimeoutMS=300000&socketTimeoutMS=300000&readPreference=secondary
```

(Make sure that the ulimit settings and net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time are optimized for mongodb)
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/diagnostics/

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem when connecting to a replica set over the network and issuing a large amount of queries fast in a database initialization script.

When connecting to a single instance of mongodb on the same computer it was fine but over a network with even just a 2-3ms latency to a replica set it would throw socket closed errors.

I also changed the keep alive time on both computers to 120 in the registry. MongoDB 3.0.6 server is on Windows Server 2012, application machine is on Windows 10.

I then tried and it had no effect (restarted the mongod services on the replica set first)

Then i added the `?connectTimeoutMS=120000&socketTimeoutMS=120000` part to the query string and I had success over the network with the Replica set.

When I looked at the documentation for options I found out that the default timeouts for a *single* instance server are 30000ms BUT for a *replica set* the default is 0ms

in: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/reference/connecting/connection-settings/

see: Replicaset level options

`socketOptions.connectTimeoutMS     {Number, default: 0}    TCP Connection timeout setting.`
`socketOptions.socketTimeoutMS  {Number, default: 0}    TCP Socket timeout setting.`

This is documentation for the node.js driver. I couldn't find info on the mongoose docs about timeouts for sockets and connections only 6-7 other options. I'm currently assuming mongoose will pass the options you specify through verbatim and not whitelist only certain options. then you can specify the timeouts in an options object instead of a connection string.

Comment: I do not see the suggested timeouts of connectTimeoutMS = 0 and socketTimeoutMS = 0 as you suggested at the link provided. Has it been updated since posting your answer?